# Unable to get checkbox values for multiple page selection

Tags: php, html

the code that I have written, simply prints the selected Book's Book_id on the same page on hitting Submit button. There are multiple books displayed on screen and there is an option to view maximum of 100 books at one time on screen. However, I do not wish to see more than 10. Now when I select 3, 9 and 7 who are all displayed on page, they seem to get displayed on selecting the check boxes. 
But if I select 1, 3, 1001,243. The last chosen value from that page ie. 243 is printed on screen. Here is my code

```
            <form action="more_book_issue.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
            <?php
            include 'connect_db.php';
            include 'login_check.php';
            include 'check_box_value.php';
            $sql = "select * from Books where id NOT IN (select Book_Id from  Issued)";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);


            echo '<table class="table table-hover table-striped" id = "issue-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Other</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Issue</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>
                <th>$row[Id]</th>
                <td>$row[Title]</td>
                <td>$row[Lastname]</td>
                <td>$row[Genre]</td>
                <td>$row[Other]</td>
                <td>$row[Rate]</td>
                <td>$row[Category]</td>
              <td>"
                ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="addToCart[]" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"/>

              <?php
                "</td>

              </tr>";
            }
            ?>

            </form>
            <?php
```

and check_box_value.php is here

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['addToCart'])) {
// Counting number of checked checkboxes.
$checked_count = count($_POST['addToCart']);
echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['addToCart'] as $selected) {
    echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
    }
    echo "<br/><b>Note :</b> <span>Similarily, You Can Also Perform CRUD    Operations using These Selected Values.</span>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, you just need to do the following code before $checked_count = count($_POST['addToCart']); :

```
if (sizeof($_POST['addToCart']) > 10) {
    $_POST['addToCart'] = array_slice($_POST['addToCart'], 0, 10);
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this like you said, But it still seems to display just the last value from the most recent page

Comment: The software displays say 100 books a page, each with a increasing book_id and if we select anything from this page say 1, 2, 99 and hit submit button, on the very same page, I can see these three numbers getting printed. But If I select book_id 200,1001,600 (All 3 of them on 3 different pages), then only the last book_id from last page ie. 600 gets printed on hitting submit button.
 I am assuming that it could be because the values are not retained by the array after page changes or refreshes. I dont know. Although I have tried the session start() and arraymerge after submit